# Check if a value not exists in an message id array or message id list SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, searchfiltercollection

I want to keep tracking my messages with message id.
I want to filter my outlook messages with message id array and my exchange server is Exchange2010.

Is there a code like this;

```
  SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or);

    searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.NotIn(EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId, new string {"1","2","3","4"}));
```

or

```
 searchFilterCollection.Add(new SearchFilter.NotIn(EmailMessageSchema.InternetMessageId, new List<string>{"1","2","3","4"}));
```

Comment: You should add a tag for the relevant programming language E.G. C#

Comment: You can't filter message like that in EWS so you'll need to rethink you logic, I'd suggest you just do you filtering client side.

Comment: Thanx for suggestion @GlenScales I will create a job to process all unprocessed messages, i dont have any UI in this scope. Maybe you can recommend me another approach.